# Formatear Fecha para Guardar Formulario

Tags: python, django

Buenas tardes, tengo una vista basada en Form View:

```
class CrearPuesto(FormView):
    template_name = 'crear_puesto.html'
    form_class = PuestoForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('administracion:maestro_puestos')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(CrearPuesto, self).form_valid(form)
```

El formulario es el siguiente:

```
class PuestoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Puesto
        fields =['oficina','trabajador','fecha_inicio','fecha_fin','es_jefatura']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PuestoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
        })
        self.fields['fecha_fin'].required = False
        self.fields['es_jefatura'].required = False
```

El problema me surge al momento de guardar las fechas ya que el formato que los usuarios utilizan es d/m/y y me sale un aviso de "Introduzca una fecha válida." Mi idea es poder formatear la fecha antes de guardarla pero no se como hacerlo.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, lo único que tenía que hacer era sobreescribir el comportamiento del field 'fecha_inicio' agregando el argumento input_formats de la siguiente manera:

```
self.fields['fecha_inicio'].input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

Comment: Si solucionaste el problema, acepta tu respuesta.

Comment: Puedo aceptar mi respuesta en 2 días.

Comment: ¿Estás usando `USE_L10N` en tu settings.py?, ¿como está definido el locale en tu servidor?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con el siguiente comando:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("25/4/16", '%d/%m/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Eso si lo tengo claro pero el problema es en que método de mi clase basada en FormView lo hago.